# Positive pin on microphone

Tags: identification, microphone

Hello can anyone tell me what is the positive on this microphone ?
[image]
[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Does it have a positive and negative?

Comment: The negative one is usually connected to the case.  Is there a track coming off the top pad going to the case?

Comment: @Finbarr so it looks, it was connected to a red and black wires. See last pic I added.

Answer (score 3):

That's an [electret microphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone).

It has an internal JFET as shown here within the dotted rectangle marked "capsule":

[image]

This JFET is needed because the electret capsule is like a small capacitor and only generates very small movements of an electrical charge when sound is present.

That small signal needs to be amplified using a JFET and the external resistor to V+

The positive connection will be the output of the JFET.

To find that connection use a multimeter, one of the two pads will be connected to the **case** as well and that will be ground, then the other pin will be the positive.

Often you can see the connection between the pad and the case, I think we cannot see it on yours as there is some black stuff covering it. Maybe if you carefully remove that black stuff above the top connection we might see the track to the case. My guess is that the bottom connection is the positive.

Comment: I used a multimeter and the case it is not directly connected to the terminals. Then I used a diode test and found the info shown in the pics I added.

Comment: I think that the only thing that makes sense is to connect the ground ( negative ) to the black pin. Anyway I like have other opinion. Can I ruin something if the connection is wrong?